# Ajax response from php POST

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

The following is my ajax code:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: type,
    data: {data:cart},
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
     },
     error: function(error){
     throw new Error('Did not work');
      }
    });
```

My problem is when I check console the response is XML document instead of the POST data which is the cart. I have tried to include dataType:'text' but this is only giving me the code in my url instead of the POST data. When I use dataType:'json' I still get XML document. My php code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Send.php</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
  print_r($POST);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

What could be the problem or what do I need to add??

Comment: Get rid of the html in the php file. You are only interested in the actual data response...not an html page

Comment: what is **2nd url** in `url: url`, **2nd type** in `type: type` and **cart** in`data:{data: cart}`?

Comment: change meta content-type to `text/json` and edit `print_r` to `echo json_encode($POST);`

Comment: @AnkitSingh This is my code which I had not included  url=that.attr('action'),
 type = that.attr('method'), and the cart is an array I had created

Comment: @MirekKowieski I am still getting the same result XML document

Comment: @charlietfl when I remove the html I get no response at all

Comment: only thing in file would be `<?php
  print_r($POST);
`

Comment: There is no response in the console at all when I include only `<?php print_r($POST); ?>`

Comment: @charlietfl you were right the html was not necessary in my php file. I found the problem was with my server which is now fixed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post('url',{data:'cart'},function(response){
        console.log(response);
    });
data - is the variable name
cart  - its a static value right now (you can have dynamic value)
```

And in the server side remove all the html and just paste this code

```
<?php
  print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Comment: I don't understand the $.post part of your code please elaborate why $.post is necessary

Comment: It's just another way of calling ajax. if you want to use get method you can use $.get

Answer (score 0):

Try `$_POST` instead of `$POST` and watch this [php superglobal variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php).

Comment: You should add this as a comment and not really an answer.

Comment: @meteor Thanks but I had already seen this typing error and fixed it but my problem still wasn't solved

Comment: Ok. Also try to use the `$_GET` value, or the `$.post()` function in your js code. "By default, Ajax requests are sent using the GET HTTP method."

Comment: Was this helpful for you?

Answer (score -1):

First thing you don't include that port of code which explain the source of cart which you pass to the server but I think if you write it in a good form and there is no mistake it is an XML data type

1- at server side you can do this

A- convert your data to json format with this function

```
$POST=json_encode($POST);
print_r($POST);
```

B- convert to array

```
 $POST=json_decode(json_encode($POST));
print_r($POST):
```

2- at client side before send data to the server you can use one of any third party script which work on converting xml to json there are more on github.

Comment: "Try"?!?? If you are not sure and want to check with OP, you should rather comment and not post as an answer.

Comment: Iam sure that your data is in xml format , it is the question how is written by a person don't know what his data type is so I convert it to json object not to what he want to be understand the difference in both cases here we are not in exam room I want him to understand what happen not to solve it but only